# How to get the vertices of a selected edge in igraph R

Tags: r, igraph

How do I get the index of the two vertices of a selected edge, using the graph package in R?

```
set.seed(5)
g <- igraph::erdos.renyi.game(1000, 1/1000)
E(g)[100]
```

This returns

```
+ 1/473 edge from e82dd81:
[1] 112--483
```

What I would like to have returned is `112`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
get.edgelist(g)[100,]
#[1] 112 483
get.edgelist(g)[100,][1]
#[1] 112
```

Or

```
get.edges(g, es = 100)[,1]
#[1] 112
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
as.integer(V(g)[inc(E(g)[100])][1]) # get vertices incident on an edge
#[1] 112
```